# SAPUI5 chart measures name based on variable

Tags: charts, sapui5

I have a chart that compares one year's values to another years'. What I would like to do is to use variables in the definition of the measures so that the legend shows the years' numbers (from the variables). I tried assigning the variables to the 'name' configuration of the chart but I get an error when I do this. Currently, I have it showing 'Start Year' and 'End Year' but would really like it to be the actual year numbers the user is comparing.

This is the portion of my controller that defines the measures and feeds:

```
I have two variables that start as the current year and the previous year, but the user can modify those values.
    var startYear = today.getFullYear();
    var endYear = today.getFullYear()-1;

var oDataset = new FlattenedDataset({
    dimensions: [{
        name: "KPI",
        value: "{field}"
        }],
    measures: [{
      name: "Start Year",   <- I tried putting startYear here and below but get errors
      value: "{current}"
    },{
      name: "End Year",       <- tried putting endYear here and below but got errors
      value: "{previous}"
    }],
    data: {
          path: "/bullet",
          filters: [oFilter]
        }
    });

    oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
    oVizFrame.setModel(oModel);

    oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
        plotArea: {
            dataLabel: {
                visible: true,
                formatString: '#,##0'
            },
            colorPalette: ['sapUiChartPaletteSemanticNeutral'],
            gap: {
                visible: true
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: {
                visible: false,

            }
        },
        legend: {
            title: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        title: {
            visible: true,
            text: 'Year Comparison'
        }
    });
  var feedValueAxis = new FeedItem({
      'uid': "valueAxis",
      'type': "Measure",
      'values': ["Start Year"]    <- tried putting startYear here but didn't work
    }),
    feedCategoryAxis = new FeedItem({
      'uid': "categoryAxis",
      'type': "Dimension",
      'values': ["KPI"]
    }),
    feedTargetValues = new FeedItem({
      'uid': "targetValues",
      'type': "Measure",
      'values': ["End Year"]       <- tried putting endYear here but got error
    });
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: try startYear= today.getFullYear().toString();
since getFullYear returns typeof number

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't seem to help. The problem seems to be in the definition of the measure and feedValueAxis....how do I put 'startYear' in?  For instance: do I - 

     measures: [{
          name: startYear,
          value: "{current}"
        }
And then how does the FeedValueAxis also get defined? For example, I tried different variations of this:
      var feedValueAxis = new FeedItem({
          'uid': "valueAxis",
          'type': "Measure",
          'values': startYear
        })
but get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: startYear is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
var startYear = String(today.getFullYear());
var endYear = String(today.getFullYear()-1);
//Please convert the values to string.


var oDataset = new FlattenedDataset({
dimensions: [{
    name: "KPI",
    value: "{field}"
    }],
measures: [{
  name: "Start Year",  
  value: startYear//just put the variable here without quotes
},{
  name: "End Year",     
  value: endYear //likewise
}],
data: {
      path: "/bullet",
      filters: [oFilter]
    }
});

oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
oVizFrame.setModel(oModel);

oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
    plotArea: {
        dataLabel: {
            visible: true,
            formatString: '#,##0'
        },
        colorPalette: ['sapUiChartPaletteSemanticNeutral'],
        gap: {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    valueAxis: {
        title: {
            visible: false,

        }
    },
    legend: {
        title: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    title: {
        visible: true,
        text: 'Year Comparison'
    }
});
   var feedValueAxis = new FeedItem({
  'uid': "valueAxis",
  'type': "Measure",
  'values': ["Start Year"]    
}),
feedCategoryAxis = new FeedItem({
  'uid': "categoryAxis",
  'type': "Dimension",
  'values': ["KPI"]
}),
feedTargetValues = new FeedItem({
  'uid': "targetValues",
  'type': "Measure",
  'values': ["End Year"]      
});

       //Hope this works.
```

Comment: that didn't do what I wanted, I wanted "Start/End Year" text to be the actual year and the value to be the data point (not the year).

Answer (score 0):

I did finally get this to work - I think I had some other issues causing this not to work, but once I got those cleared up this worked:

```
createDataset: function(sPath, sYr, eYr){
    return new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [{
            axis : 1,
            name: "Month",
            value: "{month}"
        }],
        measures: [{              
          name: eYr,          << this contains the year I want in legend
          value: "{current}"
        },{
          name: sYr,          << this contains the year I want in legend
          value: "{previous}"
        }],
        data: {
          path: sPath

        }
    });
},
createFeedItem: function(sYr, eYr) {
    return new FeedItem({
      'uid': "valueAxis",
      'type': "Measure",
      'values': [   sYr, eYr ]          << this contains the year I want in legend, same values as when FlattenedDataSet is created
    });
},

createCatItem: function() {
   return new FeedItem({
      'uid': "categoryAxis",
      'type': "Dimension",
      'values': ["Month"]
    });
},
```